# Swift 2: JSON response from query with attribute

Tags: ios, json, mkmapview, nsurlconnection, swift2

I'm using the iOS map view and I want to add annotations based on coordinates I get from a JSON request. All of this works, but now I want to search for the ID of a database entry based on the title so I can pass it on the a new view and this is where it all goes wrong.

When I try to parse the ID I get back from my JSON request I always get the error:

> "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Can anyone tell me how I can add the result I get back from the JSON request so that I can use it in for the pinview.tag please.

My code:

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation:MKAnnotation!)    -> MKAnnotationView! {

let title = annotation.title
var activityIdPin = NSInteger();
let reuseId = "pin"
var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView

    do {
        let post:NSString = "name=\(title)"

        NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "URL")!
        let postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

        let postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postData
        request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        var reponseError: NSError?
        var response: NSURLResponse?
        var urlData: NSData?

        do {
            urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            reponseError = error
            urlData = nil
        }

        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

        for anItem in jsonData as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {

            activityIdPin = (anItem["ACTIVITY_ID"] as! NSInteger);


            if annotation is MKUserLocation {
                //return nil
                return nil
            }
            if pinView == nil {
                //println("Pinview was nil")
                pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
                pinView!.canShowCallout = true
                pinView!.animatesDrop = true
                pinView!.tag = activityIdPin;
            }

            let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton // button with info sign in it
            pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
        }

        //      id = (jsonData["ACTIVITY_ID"] as? Int)!;
    }   catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)}
            return pinView

}
```

And the other thing is that if I set the $name attribute in my php file myself, I do get the correct result back in my project. It's only when I try to add the attribute from my project that it fails.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I'm very new to IOS development, so forgive me if my code looks like a mess.

Comment: Use this to see the JSON clearly http://jsonprettyprint.com that will help you figure out the structure. Which part is causing the crash. Your force casting a couple of things. Figure that out first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, i will try the pretty print, and the part that's causing the crash is this :  activityIdPin = (anItem["ACTIVITY_ID"] as! NSInteger);

Comment: I got it to work, and learned some new debugging skills in the process.

The problem is/was that the attribute I was sending in my post request: let post:NSString = "name=\(title)" was an optional field and apparently Swift adds the optional parameter in the request. So I changed the attribute to:  let title:NSString = annotation.title!!;

And now it works.

Comment: An essential tool. Good job.